# How to start tracking a folder in TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I renamed and moved some folders around in TortoiseSVN, and somehow one of them is not being tracked, or it's being tracked but by another URL. I really don't know.

I renamed the directory `AutomateRegressionProject` to `automate_regression_project`. When I try to commit just that folder (`AutomateRegressionProject)`, I get this error :

```
Error: '/svn/users/MH031989/AutomateRegressionProject/doc' path not found
```

And when I try to commit the folder above it (`MH031989`), I can't because it says there's nothing new to commit. However, when I try to update `MH031989`, I get this :

```
Skipped obstructing working copy: C:\Users\MH031989\Desktop\MH031989\automated_regression  
Warning!: One or more files are in a conflicted state.
```

I want `automate_regression_project` to be tracked under `MH031989`, but I'm a version control newbie who doesn't understand the terminology or the actual problem. Please help.

Comment: When you say you renamed the directory, did you do so using TortoiseSVN->rename, or right-click drag and use a TortoiseSVN command to move the folder; or, did you just use normal Windows renaming methods? If you did not tell TortoiseSVN you were renaming the folder, then it has no way to track the rename.

Comment: I did it using the normal windows renaming method.

Comment: @MichaelHagar you had to do it via TortiseSVN > Rename. Start over.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from what's been said, you could use tortoise's Add command to add the renamed folder to version control, but as has been mentioned you would then lose the history of that folder and any files within (tortoise will just see it as a new folder that's been added).